# C/C++: Why does an iostream allocate more memory at runtime than printf?

Tags: c++, c, memory, allocation

I noticed this today and thought it was interesting:

I compiled a basic "hello world" first in C and then in C++

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("a\n");
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And ran both of them through **valgrind**. The C version (even when compiled with **g++**) showed **1,024 bytes allocated**, while the C++ version showed **73,728 bytes allocated**

That seems like a pretty massive difference -- what exactly is going on there?

And a second thought, why is even a full kilobyte needed to run the C version?

Thanks anyone who can help me understand!

**Update**:

Thanks everyone for your responses!

It looks like including `<iostream>` has a one-time initialization cost of a little over 72,000 bytes, and the `cout` itself only uses the same kilobyte as `printf`.

Just for kicks, I wrote the following and tested it:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class minified_output_stream {
    void output(const char* text) {
        printf(text);
    }

    public:
        minified_output_stream& operator<<(const char* text) {
            output(text);
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
    minified_output_stream min_cout;

    min_cout << "A\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And found that the binary which used this "imitation cout" only allocated 1 kilobyte of memory at runtime according to valgrind. It might not be entirely practical, but it's definitely interesting, and helps (or helps me at least) to understand more of what's going on under the hood in C++ vs C

Comment: What's going on here is the C++ library doing its job.

Comment: Congratulations.  You've discovered software bloat.  ;-)

Comment: You can also check how much `malloc(1)` is allocating...

Comment: You might like the article at https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html which explains some of what you asked ... and goes into much greater detail about *other stuff* than you expect :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well obviously. I'm asking what that job is. Some people seem to think I'm criticizing or have some feelings about it. I don't, I'm curious

Comment: You might be surprised to learn how much work `<<` does, and what output streams have to do to deliver output to a stream, and then pat themselves on the back for a job well done. It involves constructing sentry objects, buffers, do all sorts of amazing things... It's a lot of work. iostreams are well known for bloat.

Comment: What happens to the C version if you replace `printf` with `puts`?

Comment: For testing you should do BOTH in c++ and use `printf` in C++ to get a more accurate result.
Streams are way more powerful and offer a lot of quality-of-life improvements but also sadly lack a lot of the `printf` families charm and features. In general streams come at a hefty onetime setup cost but at runtime the performance is still decent (albite due to all the template magic/terror never as lean or fast as `printf` )

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same result on my x86-64 Linux. Running it in a loop shows no repeated allocs, which means it's a one-time initialization thing.
Running zero times shows that with g++, the and larger alloc ( 72,704 bytes) happens simply because of compiling with `g++` as opposed to gcc, ergo it's part of c++'s standard library's initialization.
The remaining 1024 one-time alloc is then the same as with `printf`. Some global state initialization related to stdio, probably. Upon closer inspection, it's the allocation of stdout's output buffer. It's 1024 because the output file is being detected as a terminal, which only does line-bufferring by default. Redirecting to a nonterminal, e.g., /dev/null, causes the allocation to go to 4096 for full bufferring.

Comment: Thanks for running that check! Everyone's given helpful answers. It looks like including <iostream> has a one-time initialization cost of 72,704 bytes, and the cout itself only allocates the same 1 kilobyte as printf. All this is pretty fascinating to me

Comment: @anothergreenhorse: Yeah, C++ streams use facet objects, where stuff like character type tables are reachable (via a chain of pointers) from the stream itself.  Makes it difficult for the optimizer to remove them.  Even though it can prove you never call any of the locale-dependent functions that would use that information, it isn't allowed to change the memory layout of the classes.

Comment: @anothergreenhorse I'm too lazy/busy to really go find out the reason, but superficially, the malloc is getting called from glibc's filedoalloc.c file, which seems like is allocating the buffer for stdout. Why only 1024? When I do `valgrind a.out >/dev/null` the size gets upped to 4096, which is more reasonable for an IO buffer. The reason for 1024 is very likely that libc's detecting the output's a terminal (in the redirection-less case), which only gets line-buferred. 1024 seems sufficient for line buffering + as a workspace for stuff like printf("%d", 42000)` conversions etc.

Comment: @anothergreenhorse iostream at least synchronizes with libcs stdio (theoretically it could also reuse the same output buffer), so the stdio needs gets  initialized the same.